# react-navigation : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(routeConfigs)')

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I just updated my expo project and and tried upgrading react-natigation from v3 to v4 using this guide but I have this error message. Can't find what went wrong

[Upgrading from 3.x | React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/upgrading-from-3.x/)

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(routeConfigs)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use react-navigation v5, because in this version many problems solved, well documented, fully supported web and everything is components. You can change routes configs dynamically by changing state.

If you want to go to v4 from v3, I think it's worth the time to migrate to v5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have empty navigator initialization somewhere

createStackNavigator should have object as first param
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator/